# My website will scroll but wont reveal the rest of the page. What is wrong?

Tags: html, css

[My site](http://www.wdwfantasy.com.magic-kingdom)

That page has text after the picture but wont scroll further down. Is it because my footer?

Any Tips?

Comment: provide the code or any link

Answer (score -2):

For horizontal scrollbar, add

overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;

For vertical scrollbar, add

overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;

both horizontal and vertical scrollbar, add

overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:scroll;

Add these overflow to the body tag.